# Struts errors/messages with div, not span

Tags: struts2

We add Struts errors and messages using `ActionSupport.addActionError(...)` and `addActionMessage(...)` and then output the results using `<actionerror class="x"/>` and `<actionmessage class="x"/>`.

When these tags output the messages they output in the form: `<ul><li><span  class="x">msg</span></li></ul>`

As you can see you can specify the css class (in this example 'x') to apply formatting.  Problem is that we want to apply the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` css properties and you can't use these properties (I gather) with `<span>` elements - only with `<div>` elements.

So is there anyway you can get these Struts tags to output error/message using a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`?

Thanks.

---

Update:

As per the answer/workaround below, I just enclosed the struts tag within a div:

```
<div class="error-status">
  <s:actionerror cssClass="error"/>
  <s:actionmessage cssClass="status" />
</div>
```

The error-status CSS class set the properties on the LI:

```
.error-status LI { MARGIN-TOP: 5px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 5px; display: block; }
.error { COLOR: red }
.status { color: #0066CC }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply margin to spans if you also apply `display:block`.

But the optimal solution is to apply margin to the `li` elements.

Comment: Thanks Chetan.  It appears that using display:block with span only works on IE - not on Firefox.

Comment: Yes, because span is meant to be an inline element. Masquerading it as a block element is non-standard. That is why the optimal solution is to add margins to li.